# Can jQuery Galleria.js load non-image file types, e.g., .html files or other content types such as HTML5 Video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria, image-viewer

I'm wondering if galleria.js, http://galleria.aino.se, can load HTML pages or just images (.png, .jpg, .gif)?

I tried just plugging in an .html file but it didn't work, was wondering if loading html files into the viewer might be an option i'm not seeing,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: **no**. Galleria is mainly an image veiwer. But you can load HTML content and place it above the image, as seen here: http://aino.github.com/galleria/demos/layer/one.html